# Why APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG returns wrong value?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following Apex 20.1 application

[image]

The app primary language is French but configured to take the browser language preference to show the correct language.

My browser is in English and my app loads correctly in English however when calling the method : **APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG** is always returns 'fr-fr' which is different from the language displayed.

To get the value of **APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG**, I'm creating a page item with the source as follows:

[image]

Why is this value different from the language loaded in the pages? Am I doing something wrong?

Inside my code, I need to know the language displayed to the user to perform some language-dependant tasks.